# what is the best way to retrieve id from android app link?

Tags: php

what is the best way to retrieve id from android app link?

let say i have these link:

> https://market.android.com/details?id=com.prey&hl=en
>
> https://market.android.com/details?id=org.prowl.wifiscanner&feature=related_apps
>
> https://market.android.com/details?id=com.asurion.android.mobilerecovery.sprint&feature=related_apps

i just want to get the app id : com.prey or org.prowl.wifiscanner or com.asurion.android.mobilerecovery.sprint, whether or not user enter other params after the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that nicely with two lines:

```
$url = parse_url("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.prey&hl=en");
parse_str($url['query'], $vars);

echo $vars['id']; // => com.prey
```

Run it: http://codepad.org/BisV1HC0

Manual: [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php), [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use parse_url, then use parse_str for query string.

```
$query = parse_url($url, "PHP_URL_QUERY");
parse_str($query, $output);
$id = $output['id'];
```